# Xubuntu 13.10: No hibernate button on logout dialog

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, suspend, hibernate, logout

I've just installed Xubuntu 13.10. There is no "hibernate" button, only the "suspend" button. How can I activate it? I had installed Lubuntu 13.10 before, and the button was there and it did a correct hibernate and wakeup.

Comment: Yes, I have swap. I have changed nothing in the configuration of my hardware. Just installed Xubuntu into /dev/sda2 (after formatting), where previously Lubuntu was living.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found a workaround, [included in this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1241786), kidly filed by the generous Urs Fleisch.

Make a file with nano, leafpad, or some other text editor

> /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

with the following contents:

> [Re-enable hibernate by default]
>   Identity=unix-user:*
>   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
>   ResultActive=yes

Note that the action must be "org.freedesktop.**login1**.hibernate" and not "org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate" as described in [Ubuntu's instructions for 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html.) hibernation.

Comment: Works! Shall I file a bug report for Xubuntu? The report you cite is for Lubuntu, which is strange because under Lubuntu, it worked out of the box. And there is still one thing missing: The screen is not locked after wakup, which is IMHO a grave security hole!